# Part of my mesh is black even though I have no nodes attached

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh

So I am making a model and the mesh has turned black in a weird spot even though I dont have nodes attached or anything! Why is it like this?
[image]
Keep in mind that the painted tail is a separate object :)

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I had a piece of geometry that was poking through the outer wall, causing the issue.